# Get adjacent elements in a two-dimensional array?

Tags: algorithm, arrays, language-agnostic, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional array, say

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 2 3 4 0
0 9 1 5 0
0 8 7 6 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

And i need to get all the numbers adjacent to 1(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

Is there a less ugly solution than:

```
topLeft = array[x-1][y-1]
top  = array[x][y-1]
topRight = array[x+1][y-1]
# etc
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you're not worried about the order, the cleanest is probably to use a couple of loops:

```
result = new List<int>(8);
for (dx = -1; dx <= 1; ++dx) {
    for (dy = -1; dy <= 1; ++dy) {
        if (dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
            result.Add(array[x + dx][y + dy]);
        }
    }
}
```

If the order is important, you can construct a list of all the (dx, dy) in the order you want and iterate over that instead.

As pointed out in the comments, you probably want to add boundary checks. You could do that like this (assuming order doesn't matter):

```
List<int> result = new List<int>(8);
for (int dx = (x > 0 ? -1 : 0); dx <= (x < max_x ? 1 : 0); ++dx)
{
    for (int dy = (y > 0 ? -1 : 0); dy <= (y < max_y ? 1 : 0); ++dy)
    {
        if (dx != 0 || dy != 0)
        {
            result.Add(array[x + dx][y + dy]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to take into account edge cases. If the specification of (x, y) is (0, 0) then your array indices will be out of bounds. Since this looks like C# code that means you'll get an exception.

Comment: It can be made cleaner if you pull the boundaries out. dxmin = x > 0 ? -1 : 0; dxmax = x < x_max ? 1 : 0. Then the first for loop would be for (int dx = dxmin; dx <= dxmax; dx++)

Answer (score 13):

personally, the loops are more ugly than the original.

```
topLeft  = array[ x - 1 ][ y - 1 ]
top      = array[ x     ][ y - 1 ]
topRight = array[ x + 1 ][ y - 1 ]

midLeft  = array[ x - 1 ][ y     ]
midRight = array[ x + 1 ][ y     ]

botLeft  = array[ x - 1 ][ y + 1 ]
bot      = array[ x     ][ y + 1 ]
botRight = array[ x + 1 ][ y + 1 ]
```

But without specifying what you want the values for - what you do in the different directions implies whether you want the values in separate variables or not.

For game of life style processing, you usually want to be working on a bitpattern anyway rather than an array of individual values, and you can scan horizontally inspecting only three of the eight cells at a time using accumulators and temporaries. For graphics convolutions, use an existing library with a 3x3 kernel.

The other way of dealing with boundaries is to expand the array by one cell in each direction. This avoids expensive branches in the convolution code.

Comment: While searching about something else I stumbled upon your answer. Very nice solution. I wonder... would it be possible apply something similar if the array was like a Pascal pyramid? Not "a" Pascal pyramid, just the shape: one entry at the top, two at the middle and three at the bottom?

Answer (score 12):

I'd probably go for a constant list of dx, dy for each direction, like so:

```
struct {
    int dx;
    int dy;
} directions[] = {{-1,-1,},{-1,0,},{-1,1},{0,-1},{0,1},{1,-1},{1,0},{1,1}};
```

Then you'd iterate over the directions using a simple loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    // use x + directions[i].dx;
    // use y + directions[i].dy;
}
```

You can of course use `sizeof(directions) / sizeof(directions[1])` instead of the `8` above.

Comment: this is probably the nicest looking implementation

Comment: Hi, what would `x` and `y` be here? Thanks.

Comment: This is clean, but after adding the boundy checks, it may be as clean.

Comment: @elifiner, what is the language of the snippet?
I cannot see a relation between the struct and directions var/const array.
Is it a pseudo code snippet?

Answer (score 3):

python generator to get the adjacent nodes in a given matirx

```
def gen_adjacent_node(matrix_2d, node=(0,0)):
    rows = len(matrix_2d)
    columns = len(matrix_2d[0])
    for r in [-1, 0, 1]:
        for c in [-1, 0, 1]:
            if r == c == 0:
                continue
            # check valid index
            if 0 <= node[0]+r < rows and 0 <= node[1]+c < columns:
                # print((node[0]+i, node[1]+j))
                yield (node[0]+r, node[1]+c)
```

Comment: Since `yield` is an python specific operator, you might also include an example on how one can use/print the result of this function?

Answer (score 2):

In `C++` this can look like:

```
vector<int> adj;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  if (i != 4) adj.push_back(array[x + i/3 - 1][y + i%3 - 1]);
```

This is not very clear solution but very short.

Comment: that solution doesn't generalize at all

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Ruby solution. The algorithm should be evident even for readers who are not familiar with Ruby. Note how I've computed the rows and columns to be iterated over (which would be written similarly in most languages). This seems to me much cleaner than, for example, "from `max(r-1, 0)` to `min(r+1, arr.size-1)`" for the indices of the rows to iterate.

```
def adjacent(arr, r, c)
  rows_ndx = arr.each_index.select { |i| (i-r).abs < 2 }
  cols_ndx = arr.first.size.times.select { |j| (j-c).abs < 2 }
  rows_ndx.each_with_object([]) do |i,a| 
    cols_ndx.each { |j| a << arr[i][j] unless [i,j] == [r,c] }
  end
end

arr = [
  [-1,  2,  3,  4],
  [-2,  9,  1,  5],
  [-3,  8,  7,  6],
  [-4, -5, -6, -7]
]

(0..2).each do |i|
  (0..3).each do |j|
    puts "adjacent to #{arr[i][j]} at r=#{i}, c=#{j} = #{adjacent(arr, i, j)}"
  end
end
```

prints

```
adjacent to -1 at r=0, c=0 = [2, -2, 9]
adjacent to  2 at r=0, c=1 = [-1, 3, -2, 9, 1]
adjacent to  3 at r=0, c=2 = [2, 4, 9, 1, 5]
adjacent to  4 at r=0, c=3 = [3, 1, 5]
adjacent to -2 at r=1, c=0 = [-1, 2, 9, -3, 8]
adjacent to  9 at r=1, c=1 = [-1, 2, 3, -2, 1, -3, 8, 7]
adjacent to  1 at r=1, c=2 = [2, 3, 4, 9, 5, 8, 7, 6]
adjacent to  5 at r=1, c=3 = [3, 4, 1, 7, 6]
adjacent to -3 at r=2, c=0 = [-2, 9, 8, -4, -5]
adjacent to  8 at r=2, c=1 = [-2, 9, 1, -3, 7, -4, -5, -6]
adjacent to  7 at r=2, c=2 = [9, 1, 5, 8, 6, -5, -6, -7]
adjacent to  6 at r=2, c=3 = [1, 5, 7, -6, -7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isValidPos(int i, int j, int n)
{
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > n - 1 || j > n - 1)
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

void adjacentElements(int arr[][3], int i, int j)
{
    int n = 3;
    // first row
    if (isValidPos(i - 1, j - 1, n))
        cout << i - 1 << j - 1 << " ";
    if (isValidPos(i - 1, j, n))
        cout << i - 1 << j << " ";
    if (isValidPos(i - 1, j + 1, n))
        cout << i - 1 << j + 1 << " ";
    // second row
    if (isValidPos(i, j - 1, n))
        cout << i << j - 1 << " ";
    if (isValidPos(i, j + 1, n))
        cout << i << j + 1 << " ";
    // third row
    if (isValidPos(i + 1, j - 1, n))
        cout << i + 1 << j - 1 << " ";
    if (isValidPos(i + 1, j, n))
        cout << i + 1 << j << " ";
    if (isValidPos(i + 1, j + 1, n))
        cout << i + 1 << j + 1 << " ";
}

int main()
{
    int arr[3][3] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {

            cout << i << j << " "
                 << " = [ ";
            adjacentElements(arr, i, j);
            cout << "]" << endl;
        }
        // cout << endl;
    }
}
```

output

```
00  = [ 01 10 11 ]
01  = [ 00 02 10 11 12 ]
02  = [ 01 11 12 ]
10  = [ 00 01 11 20 21 ]
11  = [ 00 01 02 10 12 20 21 22 ]
12  = [ 01 02 11 21 22 ]
20  = [ 10 11 21 ]
21  = [ 10 11 12 20 22 ]
22  = [ 11 12 21 ]
```

Comment: outputs the adjacent position of a particular position in a matrix in c++

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution facing a similar problem recently, with boundary checking. I find it more readable than some of the other suggestions here. You could embed the boundary checking into the loop, but I find this way more readable.

```java
List<int[]> getSurroundingVals(int[][] array, int x, int y) {
    List<int[]> surroundingVals = new ArrayList<>();

    // Set offset indices to loop around the given cell coords
    row_min = Math.max(x - 1, 0);
    row_max = Math.min(x + 1, array.length - 1);
    col_min = Math.max(y - 1, 0);
    col_max = Math.min(y + 1, array[0].length - 1);

    // Loop through the surrounding cells and collect the values
    for (int i = row_min; i <= row_max; ++i) {
        for (int j = col_min; j <= col_max; ++j) {
            if (!(i == 0 && j == 0)) {
                surroundingVals.add(new int[]{array[x + i][y + j]});
            }
        }
    }
    
    return surroundingVals;
}
```