# Checking if two tiles are touching and are adjacent in NASM Assembly

Tags: algorithm, assembly, nasm

Suppose that I have a 2D array, and I want to check whether one slot is adjacent and touching with another.

Suppose that the coordinates are in the 4-byte variables: `OneX`, `OneY`, `TwoX`, `TwoY`.

The solution I had for a while was that if you have the differences `OneX - OneY` and `TwoX - TwoY` and add them, if the result is either `1` or `-1`, then yes, the slots are adjacent and touching.

```
mov EBX,[oneX]
sub EBX,[oneY]
mov ECX,[twoX]
sub ECX,[twoY]
add EBX,ECX
; Compare EBX with 1 or -1.......
```

This almost works. But no - given a format (x,y), take: (3,3) and (0,1). They're clearly not adjacent nor touching, but the function will say they are.

The question at [Get adjacent elements in a two-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035522/get-adjacent-elements-in-a-two-dimensional-array) is somewhat useful, but it focuses on finding all adjacent  matches, whereas I want to check for two specific slots instead.

The structure of my array is like this:

```
map: dd 'a','b','c','d'  ; Double words just to make my life easier
```

Which is interpreted like

```
a b
c d
```

It's a square map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to Add them! And you are also substracting incorrect variables :).

You have to have two conditions `OneX - TwoX` and `OneY - TwoY` : both has to be 1, 0 or -1.

For example One is [4,5] and Two is [5,5] >= `OneX - TwoX = -1` and `OneY - TwoY = 0` => it is adjanced tile.

EDIT : For non-diagonal, there are two approaches :

a)One of condition must be 0 and the other one must be 1 or -1

b)Adding absolute value of `OneX - TwoX` and absolute value of `OneY - TwoY` must be 1

Comment: What if I want to disable diagonal check? For instance, I don't want (1,2) and (2,1) to evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some practical code, based on @libik answer:

#### Optimized for speed:

```
; eax = OneX-TwoX; ecx = OneY-TwoY
        mov    eax, [OneX]
        mov    ecx, [OneY]
        sub    eax, [TwoX]
        sub    ecx, [TwoY]

; eax = abs(eax); ecx=abs(ecx)
        mov    ebx, eax
        mov    edx, ecx
        sar    ebx, 31
        sar    edx, 31
        xor    eax, ebx
        xor    ecx, edx
        sub    eax, ebx
        sub    ecx, edx

; eax=abs(delta1)+abs(delta2); if eax = 1, jump to where needed
        add    eax, ecx
        dec    eax
        lz     .adjacent
```

#### Optimized for size:

```
; eax = abs(OneX-TwoX); ecx = abs(OneY-TwoY)
        mov    eax, [OneX]
        mov    ecx, [OneY]
        sub    eax, [TwoX]
        jns    @f
        neg    eax
@@:
        sub    ecx, [TwoY]
        jns    @f
        neg    ecx
@@:
; eax=abs(delta1)+abs(delta2); if eax = 1, jump to where needed
        add    eax, ecx
        dec    eax
        lz     .adjacent
```

#### Including diagonal cases

Replace `add  eax, ecx` with `or  eax, ecx`