# How to get an element to recognize/identify other elements around it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been building a game based on Tetra Master from Final Fantasy IX with JS/jQuery and have run into a problem concerning how to get card (div) to recognize any of the other cards around it and get their IDs.

Here's the layout: https://codepen.io/ElecRei/pen/MEXZpd

**HTML:**

```
<div id="card_mat"></div>

    <br>

    <button id="submit" type="button" disabled>End Turn</button>

    <br><br>
```

**JS/jQuery** (Part that generates cards on board):

```
var cardMat = document.getElementById("card_mat");

for(i=1; i <= 16; i++){

    $(cardMat).append("<div class='panel' id='" + i + "'><span></span></div>");
    console.log("Panel " + i + " created.");

}
```

So the cards are laid out into a 4x4 grid but at the moment they essentially are just cards in a row. What I want to do is that if a card is placed next to an opponent's card, your card can recognize it despite not being right next to it in the code.

For [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlQQ4.png) if I placed a card in the first slot it could give me the IDs of the cards to the right, bottom-right and bottom of it.So is there any way to do this in any way or is JS/jQuery not able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For a more dynamic solution** (where the array can be `NxN` and not fixed `4x4`), I suggest you use `x`, `y` to identify every element and implement the logic of finding adjacent elements. There are some proposals here:

- [Get adjacent elements in a two-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035522/get-adjacent-elements-in-a-two-dimensional-array)

A **static solution** would be to use an array `siblings_of` with the information you want. That means that `siblings_of[ id ]` will return you a list of the IDs of all the adjacent tiles.

example follows (run the snippet and click on a tile to see what happens):

```js
var siblings_of = [];

siblings_of[1] = [2, 5, 6];
siblings_of[2] = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7];
siblings_of[3] = [2, 4, 6, 7, 8];
siblings_of[4] = [3, 7, 8];

siblings_of[5] = [1, 2, 6, 9, 10];
siblings_of[6] = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11];
siblings_of[7] = [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12];
siblings_of[8] = [3, 4, 7, 11, 12];

siblings_of[9] = [5, 6, 10, 13, 14];
siblings_of[10] = [5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15];
siblings_of[11] = [6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16];
siblings_of[12] = [7, 8, 11, 15, 16];

siblings_of[13] = [9, 10, 14];
siblings_of[14] = [9, 10, 11, 13, 15];
siblings_of[15] = [10, 11, 12, 14, 16];
siblings_of[16] = [11, 12, 15];

function mark_siblings(id) {
  siblings_of[id].forEach(function(item) {
    $('#' + item).addClass('marked');
  });
}

function reset() {
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $('.marked').removeClass('marked');
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.panel').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    reset();
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    mark_siblings(id);
  })
});
```

```css
.card_mat {
  width: 220px;
}

.panel {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.marked {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.selected {
 background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card_mat">
  <div class="panel" id="1">1</div>
  <div class="panel" id="2">2</div>
  <div class="panel" id="3">3</div>
  <div class="panel" id="4">4</div>
  <div class="panel" id="5">5</div>
  <div class="panel" id="6">6</div>
  <div class="panel" id="7">7</div>
  <div class="panel" id="8">8</div>
  <div class="panel" id="9">9</div>
  <div class="panel" id="10">10</div>
  <div class="panel" id="11">11</div>
  <div class="panel" id="12">12</div>
  <div class="panel" id="13">13</div>
  <div class="panel" id="14">14</div>
  <div class="panel" id="15">15</div>
  <div class="panel" id="16">16</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I target the elements within the array? I like this solution but I'm having trouble getting the value to compare.

For example how can I target the array withing: siblings_of[1] = [2, 5, 6];?

Comment: `siblings_of` keeps only numbers, no jquery objects with your divs. When you ask for the siblings of an ID, you get back an array of IDs. You can then iterate this array and create the jquery objects of the equivalent divs by using `$('#'+id)`. I am doing this inside `mark_siblings(id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuerys `.siblings();`

If you have your cards in a 4x4 grid with the syntax like,

```
<div id="grid">
    <div id="card1"></div>
    <div id="card2"></div>
    <div id="card3"></div>
    <div id="card4"></div>
    ....
</div>
```

You can use `.siblings()` to see the siblings around a DOM element.

For example,

```
$("#card2").siblings().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Changes `card1`, `card3`, `card4`, `cardn...` background color to red.

**Edit**

You need to create a function to do it. It cannot be done using just one jQuery method. (Maybe it can)

I created a function to find the siblings for the top row only. The process is similar for the other rows.

I created a [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/VtjXcC3OaZdH1JXFddwq?p=preview) to show it.

Observe the `Console.log()` messages.

You can learn more about `.eq()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).

Also learn more about `.siblings()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: could also use .prev(); or .next();

Comment: I think this is not what the OP asks for... I understand that siblings of card2 would be: 1,3,5,6,7

Comment: @tgogos Updated my answer.

Comment: So I would need to make a function that would check if the selected card matches and if it does display it's siblings (ex, if selected card == 1 then it's siblings are 2,5,6)?

**Edit:** When you store the siblings into an array is that so if I needed to use those values in another function they're already there?

Comment: @ElecRei Yes. The example I provided does the first row. Follow the example, but keep in mind to be careful about the left column and right column as well as the bottom corners. My example will push in the **jQuery object** for the sibling. If you just want the `id` number, then just `.push()` in the value of the `id`

Comment: @ElecRei Yes. I assume you want to do some logic on the sibling objects. This way the objects are in the array ready to manipulate. You call the function, and it will return the sibling objects in an array (Only top row) wherever you need it.

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do. Also to clarify how do I call the function if it's in a variable? I haven't done anything like that at this point.

Comment: You simply do `var resultReturned = nameOfFunction(params);` In our case it's `var result = findSiblings(siblingNumber);`